# NodeJs Angular connection refused on localhost

Tags: angular, express, bitnami

I have deployed my Mean app on bitnami. When I try to make a post from angular to my express server I use the url `http://localhost:3000/mypostaccess`. All the time I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` from my browser.

However if I replace localhost with the current server IP it works. Any idea how to solve this issu, I wish I could keep using localhost to make my server call inside my app.

Comment: Put host name into config  and use separate config for local machine and for server.

Comment: Thanks man!! It works, I feel like a noob but just started with mean..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are like me and developing your app localy using let say `http://localhost:3000` as your express server and `http://localhost:4200` as your angular endpoint, where all your request will be made to your express server. This is a convinient way of developping MEAN app.

When you build your app and deploy it somewhere else your angular call made to `http://localhost:3000` won't work anymore... you need to make your call to the server instead! The generic way of doing this is crafting all your calls with a foward slash like so: `http.get('/myapp/myendpoint', ...)`. No need for localhost in front!

Now if you need to still be able to developpe using 2 seperate endpoint and build using only one endpoint  take a look at environments.ts and to this article: http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/ . 
Maybe you will want to add a variable called baseUrl that change when the environment changes...